# Adding and removing edit text dynamically with button click

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to add and remove edit text dynamically using Android studio. Currently I'm able to add the edit text dynamically, but I'm unable to remove the edit text dynamically.

This is how my code looks like:

```
// Declaration 
private LinearLayout containerLayout;
private LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpView;
private EditText[] editTextDisplay = new EditText[6];
private EditText editText;
private int totalEditTexts = 0;
private int showNo = 3;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    lpView = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(totalEditTexts < 3)
            {
                editText = new EditText(getActivity());
                containerLayout.addView(editText);
                //editText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

                lpView.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                editText.setLayoutParams(lpView);
                editText.setHint("Choice "+ showNo);

                // Creating an array to store the dynamic editText value
                editTextDisplay[totalEditTexts] = editText;

                // Incrementing count and show value at the end of every click
                totalEditTexts++;
                showNo++;
            }
        }
    });

    btnSub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(totalEditTexts > 2)
            {
                containerLayout.removeView(editText);
                editTextDisplay[totalEditTexts] = null;
                totalEditTexts--;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Appreciate if someone could help me with this, thank you!

Comment: cant check now but try this: editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: In your ``btnSub.setOnClickListener``, what is the result of ``totalEditTexts``? I think in your ``btnAdd.setOnClickListener``, ``totalEditTexts`` does not increase... Try add ``static`` to ``totalEditTexts``

Comment: @chenchuk i tried and i can only delete one dynamic edit text only

Comment: @DonaldWu the totalEditTexts is increasing in my btnAdd.setOnClickListener.